# how can optimize the "Using temporary" in this sql

Tags: mysql

My sql is:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT
    COMPANYID 
FROM
    page_view 
    FORCE INDEX ( groupData ) 
WHERE
    COMPANYID = '24259' 
    AND DELETE_FLAG = 'N' 
GROUP BY
    createTime,
    person_id,
    target_type,
    TARGETID,
    source_type 
ORDER BY
NULL 
    LIMIT 15
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are no aggregate functions in your code so you should not be using group by. And group by with distinct is almost always unnecessary (group by is distinct if coded correctly)

Comment: Thank you very much! When i remove 'DISTINCT' , index takes effect.Otherwise,
I used some aggregate functions in my init sql.Thank you again.My English is poor,
Excuse me